# Updating React Json Value Conditionally

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-redux

I didn't figure out how to edit JSON data from a Put request.(it must be PUT request)

I created some inputs as you see and I need to find a way for updating/adding new credit-debit datas on JSON data differs by "to" and "from".

Also, if a "to" value added, it must decreased from total balance and if a "from" value added, it must be added to total balance.

I created a select box and an input for this (didin't connect between json and component) 
My Updater component is as follows:

Component itself:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Updater.scss';
import Axios from 'axios';


export default class Updater extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            amount: '',
            description: '',
            from: '',
            to: '',
            date: new Date()
        }
    }


    onSubmitEdit = () => {
        Axios.put('http://localhost:8080/api/balance/add', 
        {});
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="updatercontainer">
                <div className="updaterinputs">
                 <input className="amount" name="amount"  
                    type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount"/>
                 <input className="description" name="description" 
                    type="text" placeholder="Enter Description"/>
                </div>
            <div className="selectbox">
            <select>
                <option value="From">From</option>
                <option value="To">To</option>
            </select>
                <input className="fromto" type="text"
                 name="fromto" placeholder="Enter From or To Name"/>
            </div>
            <div className="selectboxcontainer">

                <div className="button-container">
                 <a href="#" onClick={this.onSubmitEdit} 
                 className="button amount-submit">
                <span></span>Update</a>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to pass the data to be sent to the server in that second argument of the put request. store the value of each input in local state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Updater extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      amount: 0,
      description: "",
      _from: true,
      _to: false,
      date: new Date()
    };
  }

  onAmountChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      amount: e.target.value
    });
  };
  onDescriptionChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    });
  };
  onSelectTypeChange = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      [e.target.value === "from" ? "_from" : "_to"]: true,
      [e.target.value !== "from" ? "_from" : "_to"]: false
    });
    if(e.target.value !== "from" && (this.state.from != null || this.state.from !== "")) { 
      this.setState({
        to: this.state.from,
        from: null
      });
    } else if(e.target.value === "from" && (this.state.to != null || this.state.to !== "")){
      this.setState({
        from: this.state.to,
        to: null
      });
    }
  };
  onFromToChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
       [this.state._from ? "from" : "to"]: e.target.value
    });
  }
  onSubmitEdit = () => {
    Axios.put(
      "https://httpbin.org/put",
      {
        ...this.state,  
      },
      { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
    )
      .then(response => {
        // handle Response
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // handle Error
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="updatercontainer">
        <div className="updaterinputs">
          <input
            onChange={this.onAmountChange}
            className="amount"
            name="amount"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Amount"
          />
          <input
            onChange={this.onDescriptionChange}
            className="description"
            name="description"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Description"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="selectbox">
          <select onChange={this.onSelectTypeChange}>
            <option value="from">From</option>
            <option value="to">To</option>
          </select>
          <input onChange={this.onFromToChange} className="fromto" type="text"
               name="fromto" placeholder="Enter From or To Name"/>
        </div>
        <div className="selectboxcontainer">
          <div onClick={this.onSubmitEdit} className="button-container">
            <a href="#" className="button amount-submit">
              <span>Update</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Consider Reading More About [Handling Inputs, Forms, Events](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/how-to-work-with-forms-inputs-and-events-in-react-c337171b923b)

[Working Sandbox!](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-paper-qh0xh)

Comment: Thank you very much.
But one thing i found. I think you deleted the "fromto" input. But as you can see on JSON data the value from "fromto" input goes to "from" or "to" depending on your select box choice. 
It was the hardest part for me, I didin't even thought the logic.
Do you have an idea about it?

Comment: yes, since this sends to the server if the user selected "from" or "to" you can apply this to the server if you don't have control over that, just add a field.

Comment: Ok let's consider we have control over server for handling selected "from" or "to" and also an input value (not boolean)
For example; selected "from" and wrote "John", then how it goes like "from": "John" to server.

Comment: I have updated, the code.. does it meet your requirement?

Comment: this is a server-end issue or the route is invalid.

Comment: Jamal, I have a problem with added value. 
There is no problem with "to" value (when i select "to" and add its only added to "to" but when doing the opposite "from" value adding to both to and from. Do you see a problem in the code?

Comment: No, but if you want to check for your self, run the sandbox and see the response in dev tab (httpbin)

Answer (score 1):

you just need an onChange event to update the state based on the input values name

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}

//On your inputs
<input 
    className="amount" 
    name="amount" 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="Enter Amount"
    value={this.state.amount}
    onChange={() => this.handleChange(e)}
/>
```

Comment: the you will want to pass state in as the second parameter for your PUT request like John said above